# Error invoking SOAP service "No binding operation"

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a existing SOAP service which is working fine. So, I have to make changes to read `specialHeader`. I have created my own handler implementation for `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` and then have to register in the endpoint. As you can see below I have added `jaxws:handlers` section but my web service now thrown an error.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="serviceWS"
        implementor="#beanWS" address="/service">
<jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <bean class="customInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="String" value="${username}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="String" value="${password}" />
    </bean>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
<jaxws:handlers>
    <ref bean="customHandler" />
</jaxws:handlers>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Service throw me this error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can see that interceptor and handler can be executed. After that the service throw an error. Also, I have been testing just with the handler and my service run ok. Can `inInterceptors` and `handlers` work together? or are there any special trick?